# Trigonometric question about $ \cos x $/$\sin x$/$\tan x$

Tags: trigonometry

For every real number $x$ we put :   $$A(x) = \cos^2x - \sin^2x $$

1) Calculate :      $$A(\frac{\pi}{4} +3\pi)$$

2) Prove that for every real number $x$ from the sphere $ ]\frac{-\pi}{2}; \frac{\pi}{2}[ $  we have : $$ A(x) = \frac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x} $$

3) Solve in the sphere $ ]\frac{-\pi}{2}; \frac{\pi}{2}[ $ the equation $$A(x) =  \frac{1}{2} $$

I only ask questions when I really really need help and right now I need help. I'm sorry but my teacher explain the lesson very quickly in an incomprehensible way.

Comment: Note that $\cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x) = \cos(2x)$

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use the formulas $$\begin{cases}\sin(a+b)=\cos a\sin b+\sin a\cos b\\\cos(a+b)=\cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b\end{cases}$$ and run the calcs directly (trick: what happens to those formulas if $a=b$?)
2. You can just  substitute $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ (does the interval allow it?).
3. You can use $\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$.

Comment: For 1) why not just substitute directly?

Comment: @K.Power Then he'd need a different set of identities (other than $2\pi$-periodicity), namely $\sin(x+\pi)=-\sin x$. I saw no need to tell him just the special case. Of course, there are countless ways to solve this exercise.

Comment: @K.Power I might have realised now: *of course* I was not telling him to calculate explicitly $\cos^2(a+b)-\sin^2(a+b)$  and then substitute $a=\frac\pi4$ and $b=3\pi$. I was telling him to use those identities to calculate, say, $\cos\left(\frac\pi4+3\pi\right)$. I cannot warn people against all the possible bad ways to use an idea.

Answer (score 0):

(1)$$cos(a+b)=cosa.cosb-sina.sinb \\\to cos(x+x)=cos^2x-sin^2x=cos(2x)\\\to A(x)=cos(2x)\\A(\frac{\pi}{4}+3\pi)=cos2(\frac{\pi}{4}+3\pi)=cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+6\pi)\\= cos(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$$ (2)
$$A(x)=\frac{A(x)}{1}=\frac{cos^2x-sin^2x}{cos^2x+sin^2x}=\\\frac{\frac{cos^2x-sin^2x}{cos^2x}}{\frac{cos^2x+sin^2x}{cos^2x}}=\frac{1-tan^2x}{1+tan^2x}$$
(3)
$$\\A(x)=1/2 \to \\cos(2x)=\frac{1}{2}\\2x=\pm \frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi \to x=\pm \frac{\pi}{6}+k\pi ,x\in ]-\pi/2,\pi/2[\\ \to x=\pm \frac{\pi}{6}$$

Comment: Can you please explain the first one a little bit more ?

Comment: I made a proof for the first step

Comment: If you know $cos(2x)$ formula ...If not you can obtain formula for $cos(2x)$ by the primary formula(s) $cos(a+b)=cos a . cos b- sin a . sin b\\$now put $a=x,b=x \to $ then you have $$cos(a+b)=cos(x+x)=cos(2x)=cos x.cos x - sin x .sin x=\\cos^2x-sin^2x $$